# How to go direct to maps without click the link (direct go to maps after click the button "show my location")?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, geolocation, maps

1.**This is javascript file**
'''
how to go direct to maps after click the button show my location
'''

```js
function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
  }

  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }

  if(!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }

}

document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-"
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> TEST </h1>

<p> Hello! </p>
<button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
<p id = "status"></p>
<a id = "map-link" target="_blank"></a>

2. **This is HTML file**
```

**Photos**

[Main page before click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfAmb.png)

[After click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR399.png)
[After click the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enylP.png)

Comment: What is with all these tags? The only relevant is `javascript`

Comment: And what's the actual problem?

Comment: My actual problem is can't go direct to map location page without click the URL link(latitude longitude). For more understanding maybe you can see photo that I uploaded.

Comment: so you need to navigate to the link directly on button click?

Comment: yes. @seriously

Comment: When I ask for more details and you only answer with a copy of the title that doesn't really help. _"maybe you can see photo that I uploaded"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect to the location on button click.

```js
function geoFindMe() {

  const status = document.querySelector('#status');
  const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

  mapLink.href = '';
  mapLink.textContent = '';

  function success(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    status.textContent = '';
    mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
    mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
    location.href = "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}";
  }

  function error() {
    status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }

  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }

}

document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-" <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> TEST </h1>

  <p> Hello! </p>
  <button id="find-me">Show my location</button><br />
  <p id="status"></p>
  <a id="map-link" target="_blank"></a>
</body>

</html>
```